# javadoc: show also descriptions of methods from parent class

Tags: java, scala, documentation, javadoc

Is there a way to produce javadoc so that all methods accessible from the class are listed with their full description? Usually only the methods defined in that class are listed and the rest are only linked to in "methods inherited from" section.

(Obviously it is tricky to show javadoc of super classes if they're thirdparty and there's no source code/javadoc for them)

I'm also interested if this can be applied to scaladocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is possible, at least for Scala: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to get the standard Doclet to do this.  But if you were really keen you could download the source code and modify it to do whatever you wanted.

Comment: Since it is not really an answer. Whenever I'm looking for a tool someone can suggest doing it myself.

Comment: Well thanks for your "appreciation" for the effort I put in researching your question. Next time I think I won't bother trying to help you.